# Problem calling a function when it is in a .lib

Tags: c++, virtual

I have a class with a static method that looks roughly like:

```
class X {
    static float getFloat(MyBase& obj) {
        return obj.value();  // MyBase::value() is virtual
    }
};
```

I'm calling it with an instance of MyDerived which subclasses MyBase:

```
MyDerived d;
float f = X::getFloat(d);
```

If I link the obj file containing X into my executable, everything works as expected. If I'm expecting to get 3.14, I get it.

If I create a .lib that contains the X.obj file and link in the .lib, it breaks. When I call getFloat(), it's returning **-1.#IND00**. Is this some type of sentinel value that should tell me what's wrong here?

Is anything different when you link in a lib rather than an obj directly?

I don't get any compiler warnings or errors.

**Edit:**
I'm using Visual Studio 2005 on Windows XP Pro SP3. To make sure I wasn't linking old files, I cloned the value() method into a new value2() method and called that instead. The behavior was the same.

**Edit #2:**
So, if I trace into the call with my debugger, I'm finding that it isn't going into my value() method at all. Instead it's going into a different (unrelated) method. This makes me think my vtable is corrupted. I think the behavior I'm seeing must be a side effect of some other problem.

---

**Solved!** (thanks to Vlad)
It turns out I was violating the one definition rule (ODR) although it wasn't evident from the code I posted. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2007/05/17/diagnosing-hidden-odr-violations-in-visual-c-and-fixing-lnk2022.aspx) is a great article from the Visual C++ guys that explains the problem and one way to track it down. The */d1reportSingleClassLayout* compiler flag is a fantastic learning tool.

When I dumped out the my class layout for MyBase and MyDerived in the two different projects, I found differences between the calling code and the library code. It turns out I had some *#ifdef* blocks in my header files and the corresponding *#define* statement was in the precompiled header for the main project but not in the subproject (the library). Have I mentioned how evil I think preprocessor macros are?

Anyway, I'm only posting this stuff because it might be helpful to somebody else. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302446/how-can-one-inspect-a-vtable-in-visual-c) was also very helpful to me.

Comment: What platform? What development system? It matters.

Comment: Don't write solutions in questions, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem will occur when the lib and the executable have been be compiled with **different definitions of the `MyDerived` class** (i.e. different versions of the `.h`/`.hh`/`.hpp` file that declares `MyDerived`.  Completely clean and rebuild your projects.  Barring this, different compiler options *could* be responsible, though it is somewhat unlikely.

If the problem persists after rebuilding everything from scratch, then nail it by instantiating a dummy `MyDerived` object inside `getFloat`, in the library.  Use the debugger to compare the `vtable` of the dummy `MyDerived` (instantiated in the library) and the `vtable` of the `MyDerived` object reference passed as parameter (instantiated in the executable.)  Something should spring to eye right away.

Comment: You're exactly right! I'm using Microsoft's compiler and it has a flag to dump the class layout. From this I found the differences. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since a lib is just a container, if you are linking the same .obj file in both cases then as Brian says they shouldn't (can't?) be a difference.

One thing to watch is if you changed the definition of MyBase you obviously need to recompile both the library and the code using it.  For example, if you added a new virtual method to MyBase before the value method, then that would mess up the library since the v-table offset of value would be different.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference.  Just make sure that the .h files you are including correspond to the .lib that you are linking to exactly.   I suspect you may be linking to an old .lib file.

If you are using visual studio, instead of explicitly specifying the .lib file, simply right click on the project and set dependencies to the .lib project.  That way you will be sure it uses the correct .lib file.

Comment: I'm loading the library with a "#pragma comment(lib, "mylib")". I was worried about linking old files as well, so I copied the method into a new one with a new name (but the same contents) and called that method with no change in behavior.